# PowerBI - Gateway error with ODBC (Hive) Data source

Tags: odbc, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

We have PowerBI report with data source as ODBC (Hive -- connected through MS Hive ODBC driver).
Now, we need to configure gateway so that data can be refreshed periodically.
However, while adding an ODBC data source in Gateway we are getting following error.

=============

GetwayName1-PowerBI: Unable to connect to the data source undefined. 
Underlying error code: -2147467259
Underlying error message: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: Key not valid for use in specified state. ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: Key not valid for use in specified state.
DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult: -2147467259
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind: Odbc

=============

Any inputs on this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue having an AWS Athena ODBC driver as data source.
While the DSN for the 64bit driver was correctly configured in Windows and Power BI desktop could retrieve the data, it did not work in the Power BI Service with above error.

Solution was to pass in the credentials (the ones that are configured in the DSN) in the Gateway connection in Power BI Service with "Basic" authentication.

Apparently Power BI Desktop can use the impersonated credentials from the DSN configuration but the Power BI Service through the gateway cannot.